# Spring Data MongoDb - Criteria equivalent to a given query that uses $expr

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection with documents like this:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8ec4620cd3c2a4062548ec"),
    "start" : 20,
    "end" : 80
 }
```

and I want to show the documents that overlap a given percentage (50%) with an interval (startInterval = 10, endInterval = 90).

I calculate the overlaping section with the following formula:

```
min(end , endInterval) - max(start, startInterval ) / (endInterval - startInterval)
```

In this example:
min(80,90) - max(20,10) / (90-10) = (80-20)/80 = 0.75 --> 75%
Then this document will be shown, as 75% is greater than 50%

I expressed this formula in mongo shell as:

```
db.getCollection('variants').find(
  {
     $expr: {  

       $gt: [

              { 
                $divide: [
                           { 
                             $subtract: [ 
                                          { $min: [ "$end", endInterval ]  }
                                          , 
                                          { $max: [ "$start", startInterval ]  } 
                             ] 
                           }
                           , 
                           { $subtract: [ endInterval, startInterval ] }
                         ] 
              }
             , 
             overlap 
            ]
      }
  }
)
```

where

overlap = 0.5, startInterval = 10 and endInterval= 90

It works fine in mongo shell.

I'm asking for an equivalent way to calculate this using Spring Data Criteria, since the $expr functionality I used in mongo shell is still to be implemented in Spring Data Mongo.
Currently I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.0, Spring Data MongoDb 2.0.5 and mongodb 3.6.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: So what have you actually tried to write in your Java code? It does not matter if it does not work, but it is expected that you at least make some attempt at doing something.  Otherwise it just "looks like" you simply want someone to do your work for you, for free. Let's not make it "look like" that and show your attempt and someone will happily help you along.

Comment: Hello Neil
I'm sorry if it gave you that impression.
The truth is that my question is focused on seeing if some expert in Spring Data can help me on how to address this,
since the $expr functionality is still to be implemented in Spring Data Mongo as you can see in this link. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1845.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it is helpful for somebody, I finally solved my problem using $redact.

```
String redact = "{\n" + 
            "       \"$redact\": {\n" + 
            "           \"$cond\": [\n" + 
            "               {\n" + 
            "                   \"$gte\": [\n" + 
            "                       {\n" + 
            "                           \"$divide\": [\n" + 
            "                               {\n" + 
            "                                   \"$subtract\": [\n" + 
            "                                       {\n" + 
            "                                           \"$min\": [\n" + 
            "                                               \"$end\",\n" + 
            "                                           "   + endInterval + "\n" + 
            "                                           ]\n" + 
            "                                       },\n" + 
            "                                       {\n" + 
            "                                           \"$max\": [\n" + 
            "                                               \"$start\",\n" + 
            "                                           "   + startInterval + "\n" + 
            "                                           ]\n" + 
            "                                       }\n" + 
            "                                   ]\n" + 
            "                               },\n" + 
            "                               {\n" + 
            "                                   \"$subtract\": [\n" + 
            "                                   "   + endInterval + "\n" + 
            "                                   "   + startInterval + "\n" +  
            "                                   ]\n" + 
            "                               }\n" + 
            "                           ]\n" + 
            "                       },\n" + 
            "                   "   + overlap + "\n" + 
            "                   ]\n" + 
            "               },\n" + 
            "               \"$$KEEP\",\n" + 
            "               \"$$PRUNE\"\n" + 
            "           ]\n" + 
            "       }\n" + 
            "   }";


    RedactAggregationOperation redactOperation = new RedactAggregationOperation(
            Document.parse(redact)
    );
```

where RedactAggregationOperation is

```
public class RedactAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private Document operation;

    public RedactAggregationOperation (Document operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
         return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an open issue to add support for `$expr` : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/2750

In the meantime, you can use an BasicQuery:

```java
BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery("{ $expr: {'$gt': ['$results.cache.lastHit', '$results.cache.expiration']}}");
return ofNullable(mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, updateDefinition, XXXX.class));
```

You can even concatenate your existing Criteria with BasicQuery, keeping it exclusive to the `$expr`:

```java
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("results.cache.cacheUpdateRetriesLeft").gt(4);
BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery("{ $expr: {'$gt': ['$results.cache.lastHit', '$results.cache.expiration']}}");
query.addCriteria(criteria);
return ofNullable(mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, updateDefinition, XXXX.class));
```

EDIT: [The github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/2750) was marked as closed.

Answer (score 2):

Support for $expr operator in spring-data-mongodb library is still non-existent. However there is a work around solution using MongoTemplate to solve this problem -

Aggregation.match() provides an overloaded method that accepts AggregationExpression as a parameter. This method can be used to create the query for $match aggregation pipeline with $expr operator as below -

**Example usage of AggregationExpression for $match operator -**

```
Aggregation aggregationQuery = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(AggregationExpression.from(MongoExpression.create("'$expr': { '$gte': [ '$foo', '$bar'] }"))));
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregationQuery, Entity.class);
```

**Above code is the equivalent of query -**

```
db.collection.aggregate([{"$match": {"$expr": {"$gte: ["$foo", "$bar"]}}}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, Spring Data Mongo currently does not support `$expr`, so I have to use custom BSON document, and reflection of `MongoTemplate`.

```
public List<Variant> listTest() throws Exception {

    double overlap = 0.5;
    int startInterval = 10;
    int endInterval= 90;

    String jsonQuery = "{$expr:{$gt:[{$divide:[{$subtract:[{$min:[\"$end\","+endInterval+"]},{$max:[\"$start\","+startInterval+"]}]},{$subtract:["+endInterval+","+startInterval+"]}]},"+overlap+"]}}";
    Document query = Document.parse(jsonQuery);

    Method doFind = MongoTemplate.class.getDeclaredMethod("doFind", String.class, Document.class,Document.class,Class.class);
    doFind.setAccessible(true);
    return (List<Variant>) doFind.invoke(mongoTemplate, "variants", query, new Document(), Variant.class);
}

@NoArgsConstructor @Getter @Setter @ToString
public static class Variant{
    int start;
    int end;
}
```

As you may see, field mapping works OK.

Used Spring Data Mongo artifact is `org.springframework:data.spring-data-mongodb:2.1.5.RELEASE`